# How to put tcp server on another thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tcpserver

I try to write a daemon in python. But I have no idea how can I use a thread to start parallel tcp server in this daemon. And even what type of server I should use : asyncore?SocketServer?socket?

this is part of my code:

```
import os
def demonized():
   child_pid = os.fork()
   if child_pid == 0:
       child_pid = os.fork()
       if child_pid == 0:          #fork twice for demonize
           file = open('###', "r") # open file
           event = file.read()
           while event:
               #TODO check for changes put changes in list variable
               event = file.read()
       file.close()
       else:
           sys.exit(0)
   else:
       sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  demonized()
```

So in a loop I have a list variable with some data appended every circle, and I want to start a thread with tcp server that wait for connection in the loop and if client connects send it this data(with zeroing variable). So I do not need to handle multiple clients, the client will be only one at time. What is the optimal way to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could just use Twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) which is designed for network based event handling.

Comment: A presentation that recently helped me a lot — I had known about `Queue`, but the presentation introduced me to thinks like `Event` which I had seen in the Standard Library docs but not known what to do with — is David Beazley's “An Introduction to Python Concurrency” — even though David does training professionally, he has generously been putting up a lot of his slide decks for everyone to see:

http://www.slideshare.net/dabeaz/an-introduction-to-python-concurrency

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you want to avoid repeating boilerplate, Python will soon have a standard module that does the `fork()` pair and standard-I/O manipulations (which you have not added to your program yet?) that make it a daemon. You can download and use this module right now, from:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon

Running a TCP server in a separate thread is often as simple as:

```
import threading

def my_tcp_server():
    sock = socket.socket(...)
    sock.bind(...)
    sock.listen()
    while True:
        conn, address = sock.accept()
        ...
        ... talk on the connection ...
        ...
        conn.close()

def main():
    ...
    threading.Thread(target=my_tcp_server).start()
    ...
```

I strongly recommend **against** trying to get your file-reader thread and your socket-answering thread talking with a list and lock of your own devising; such schemes are hard to get working and hard to keep working. Instead, use the standard library's `Queue.Queue()` class which does all of the locking and appending correctly for you.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to append items to the list in `while event:...` loop and serving this list simultaneously?  If so then you have two writers and you must somehow protect your list.

In the sample `SocketServer.TCPServer` and `threading.Lock` was used:

```
import threading
import SocketServer
import time


class DataHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.server.list_block.acquire()
        self.wfile.write(', '.join(self.server.data))
        self.wfile.flush()
        self.server.data = []
        self.server.list_block.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    list_block = threading.Lock()

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('localhost', 0), DataHandler)
    server.list_block = list_block
    server.data = data

    t = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    t.start()

    while True:
        list_block.acquire()
        data.append(1)
        list_block.release()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: First, this solution should probably use a `Queue` instead of building one out of primitives. Second, it is not clear to me that it even runs — Python does not support calling `write()` on a list object, does it? I get `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`.

Comment: @Kirill Teplinskiy   It looks like what I need except `time.sleep(1)` my file can changes faster than sec(I can lost some information in that case). Is there some method to pause `while` loop by external event (opening connection to client) (not inside the loop)? flag\semaphore?

Comment: @ Brandon Craig Rhodes I`m not sure but maybe conversion data_list to string before sending should help. But I cant check it right now

Comment: @user1027564, yep, conversion to string is needed.  I didn't run this code before posting.  Anyway, look at the Brandon answer, especially at `Queue`.  It seems like it is what you need for exchanging information between threads.  It is new for me too :).  But I still suggest using `SocketServer.TCPServer` instead of manually working with sockets.  This is the same as the `Queue` for threads, but for network.

Comment: @Brandon Craig Rhodes, thank you for noting about `Queue`.  I'm going to study it now because it is really helpful.